# Como pegar índice do array?

Tags: java, lista, for, apex

Tenho o seguinte código APEX

```
List<integer> entrada = new List<integer>();

public static void  generateStringArray(integer entrada){
 List<String> ListaPrincipal = new List<String>();


    for(integer i = 0; i < entrada; i++){

       System.debug(entrada.get(i).toString);


    }



}
```

Estou tentando pegar o índice `i`. Quando eu o executo, ele da o seguinte erro:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Integer) from the type Integer

Comment: Com entrada[i] ao invés do get(i), funciona?

Comment: Você tem vários erros no código. Seria também interessante dizer o que é esse `integer` ? Ou será que queria antes ter colocado `Integer` ? O melhor seria colocar o código tal como o teu no seu arquivo, mas se está como tem aqui, então ainda está bem longe de compilar.

Answer (score 3):

Você está tentando pegar o índice de uma variável chamada `entrada` que é um `integer` (imagino que isto também está errado, pode ser que queira usar `Integer` ou `int`), mas na verdade o que provavelmente deseja é pegar na variável `ListaPrincipal` que é uma lista e como todo objeto lista tem o método `get()`.

Tem outros erros no código. Isto faz mais sentido:

```
List<Integer> lista = new List<Integer>();

public static void generateStringArray(int entrada) {
    if (entrada < lista.length()) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < entrada; i++) {
       System.out.println(lista.get(i));
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/GetIndex.java).

Idealmente deveria ter um retorno indicando se deu certo ou não, mas depende do requisito.

Comment: Refatorei a pergunta e o codigo

Comment: Não, você apagou a pergunta original e fez uma nova pergunta e você não pode fazer isso, tem que deixar a original e se tem novo problema você faz uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Seu código está repleto de erros:

1. Java diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas. O nome da classe é `Integer`, e não `integer`.
2. Não é possível instanciar-se interfaces diretamente. Logo, usar `new List` não é permitido. Você deve instanciar uma implementação, tal como `ArrayList`.
3. O método `System.debug` não existe. Talvez o que você queria era usar `System.out.println`.
4. Observe que você tem duas coisas diferentes chamadas de `entrada`. Uma delas é a lista e a outra o parâmetro do método `generateStringArray`. Mude o nome de uma delas para não criar confusão.
5. Observe que a `ListaPrincipal` não é usada em lugar nenhum depois de criada. Logo, é desnecessário.
6. Uma vez que `toString` é um método, você não deve esquecer de colocar o `()` nele.
7. Não use `Integer` onde `int` é o suficiente. Um `int`, por ser um tipo primitivo, nunca pode ser `null`. Já o `Integer`, por ser um objeto, pode ser `null`.

Acho que o seu código corrigido poderia ficar assim:

```
List<Integer> lista = new List<Integer>();

public static void generateStringArray(int entrada) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entrada; i++) {
       System.out.println(lista.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```